# disable flow control (pause) in linux

Tags: linux

i have a 10g interface which is connected to my upstream switch and i am receiving my other switch uplink port mirror on this port and i am analyzing it, i have disable flow control and pause on this interface inside my Linux and all connected ports such as my switches has disabled flow controlled,
but my Linux server which analyzing the port mirror is sending pause frame towards other port,
here is the output :

```
ethtool -S eno2 | grep pause
     rx_pause_frames: 0
     rx_constant_pause_events: 0
     tx_pause_frames: 7714303
ethtool -a eno2
Pause parameters for eno2:
Autonegotiate:  off
RX:             off
TX:             off
```

any idea how can i solve this?
thanks,

Comment: In hardware, flow control can be auto negotiated by default with the link partner while the interface is being brought up. (This is MAC dependent, and requires a review of the data sheet if you are writing the device driver.) Maybe the config changes aren't getting updated if the link was already up? Possibly due to driver, or MAC limitations. I'm just guessing.

Comment: After setting the `ethtool -a` pause options, have you tried restarting the interface on the Linux side? That might force a re-initialization of the MAC hardware to match the new `ethtool -a` settings, if for some reason it is not getting updated after the link partner was brought up the first time. Or setting the `ethtool -a` options before the interface is configured, and the link partner is brought up (assuming the driver allows that).